# Why does this JQuery JSON call fail?

Tags: jquery, json, get

I am trying to make a simple call to an API that returns a JSON file. I have confirmed that the URL I use works and returns valid JSON. When I try to get the JSON with this JQuery script, the alert is not triggered which makes me think something is wrong with the GET portion of the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON("http://open.nysenate.gov/legislation/2.0/search.json?term=stricken:true%20AND%20year:2009&callback=?", function(json) {
            alert("test");
        });
    });
 </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The URL does not return JSONP. If you make a cross-domain call, it has to return JSONP.

Answer (score 1):

To get around the Same Origin Policy, you can write a simple backend script (PHP, perl, Python, etc.) that scrapes the desired URL and outputs the results to your script.  Then you would just point your AJAX call to your local script instead of the remote one.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't support JSONP, try it for [yourself](http://open.nysenate.gov/legislation/2.0/search.json?term=stricken%3atrue%20AND%20year:2009&callback=test)

It's violating of [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy - you can't make an ajax call outside of your current domain. One way around this, as suggested by other answers, is to use JSONP.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the JSON object returned is not in a proper format as this returns an error

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("http://open.nysenate.gov/legislation/2.0/search.json?term=stricken:true%20AND%20year:2009&callback=?",function(json){
        alert("dsf");
    })
  .error(function() { alert("error"); });

});
```

Comment: The problem is that you cannot get JSON (or any data for that matter) from an external domain.... it has to be in JSONP format. The JSON itself is valid, you can copy it to http://jsonlint.com/ and see for yourself.

Comment: Is there a way for me to get it in the JSONP format without modifying the API?

Comment: @jeffpm: No, the sever has to support it. If you control the server, you can change it.